# Failed to open stream: Too many open files

Tags: linux, logging, php

I'm writing a PHP CLI script for a client that runs in a shared hosting. It logs to a file using a simple function like:

```
function log_entry($msg) {
    global $log_file, $log_handle;
    $msg =  "[".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."] ".$msg."\n";
    echo $msg;
    $log_handle = fopen($log_file, 'a');
    fwrite($log_handle, $msg);
}
```

And I get this error:

```
PHP Warning:  fopen(./logs/sync.20130410.log) 
[<a href='function.fopen'>function.fopen</a>]: failed to open stream: 
Too many open files in ./functions.php on line 61
```

I thought there was an issue with using the same handle, so I changed it to:

```
function log_entry($msg) {
    global $log_file;
    $msg =  "[".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."] ".$msg."\n";
    echo $msg;
    $log_handle = fopen($log_file, 'a');
    fwrite($log_handle, $msg);
    fclose($log_handle);
}
```

But that didn't work. I get the error always in the same log line. When I do `ulimit -n` I get 1024, but that shouldn't be an issue because I'm never open more than one file. Ideas?

Comment: you my be running into a file descriptor limit with your shared hosting provider

Comment: But aren't I using only one at a time with both functions? The first one is supposed to use only one through the complete execution and the second one is supposed to use one per line... or does it work differently?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/195334/apache-crashes-every-night-due-to-too-many-open-files

Comment: http://ss64.com/bash/ulimit.html ... apache could be configured to lower its ulimit to the number of files it has open, thus limiting you from opening additional files. You should check with your hosting provider on the config

Comment: @Zak This is a PHP script, but it's executed through CLI, so Apache is not in the middle

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Spotted the issue. I'm answering this just in case anyone Googles for the same reason, but I know this answer wasn't implied in the question.

I'm using BigCommerce API client and turns out that they were opening a handle per request and making my script crash. Here is how I fixed it:

BigCommerce/API/Connection.php:354-365:

```
public function put($url, $body)
{
    $this->addHeader('Content-Type', $this->getContentType());

    if (!is_string($body)) {
        $body = json_encode($body);
    }

    $this->initializeRequest();
    $handle = tmpfile();
    fwrite($handle, $body);
    fseek($handle, 0);
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_INFILE, $handle);
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, strlen($body));

    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_PUT, true);
    curl_exec($this->curl);
    fclose($handle); // Added this line

    return $this->handleResponse();
}
```

(Added the `fclose($handle);`) line.